# How to query if a GitLab merge request supports multiple reviewers?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

GitLab's documentations say that a merge request can be updated to add one or more reviewers via the `reviewer_ids` property: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr

What seems strange to me is that certain projects or merge requests or users seem to have the ability to add more than one reviewer to a merge request, while others can only have one reviewer. This is viewable in the UI at gitlab.com, with some merge requests having more than 1 reviewer (see screenshot below), while my free account only seems to allow 1 reviewer on a merge request.

Via the GitLab api, how can I detect whether a given merge request can support more than 1 reviewer? If not at the merge request level, is this something at the project or user level?

For some additional context, I'm working on building a VSCode extension for [CodeStream](https://codestream.com) to enable support for GitLab merge requests, and the ability to add reviewers is part of its functionality.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, looks like it's not documented separately, but multiple reviewers is available when multiple assignees are too: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/getting_started.html#multiple-assignees ; this is a premium+ feature. Don't think you can tell at MR or project level, except it should refuse if multiple reviewers is not available.

Comment: @Arty-chan is there anyway to query the api to see if "Premium" is enabled?

Comment: only at the namespace level but then you need to be a member with the rights to that info which I believe is only Owner. Any public project should have the feature though